# 404 on http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts in wordpress using REST API V2

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, rest, routes, wordpress-rest-api

I am getting a 404 on http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts route. I changed permalink type to plain. Still got the same issue.

If its useful, I am ubuntu 16.04 desktop recent upgrade from 15.10, suffered issues with php5.6 to 7.0 upgrade. Am now on php 7.0

Edit1: 
Tried every other permalink setting combination, no results!

Comment: As per docs what endpoints are available when you go to `http://localhost/wp-json/` ? What version of wordpress? Using plugin or built in version of `wp-json`? Sure not much detail provided here

Comment: I am using 4.8, I guess wp-json is built into this version. But I installed REST API v2 plugin(was following some tutorials, may be old ones).

Comment: FYI I am totally new to wordpress, so ask me for stupid checks too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give permission to your wp-content folder. For the change the permission please use below command in terminal.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 wp-content/
```

After the change permission is still show 404 error then allow AllowOverride for apache, below is the step:

navigated to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and opened `000-default`

All of the `AllowOverride` variables were set to None, which I replaced with `All`.

After this change enable mod using below command:

```
 a2enmod rewrite
```

And restart the apache service below is the command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I don't have `AllowOverride` variables at all in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

Comment: You need to allow read htaccess to apache. for more detail, please click on link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: After performing above step you need to change permalink from dashboard, please set permalink is post.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry to say this, but **DON'T DO THIS!** This is a really bad and dangerous answer and should not be the accepted one. With `sudo` and `-R` you're performing a *recursive operation on a whole directory* that is not only useless but also **potentially dangerous**. The wp-contents **should not have 777** rights, 755 is sufficient. See https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/

Comment: Thanks For your suggestion. I have modify my post. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`http://localhost/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts` 
should works. 
Refer https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/discovery/ for details.

Comment: so should the webserver redirect `wp-json/*` to `index.php?rest_route=*`
I receive the error when trying to save a new post.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to enable the apache rewrite module with the following command:

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then we must edit the configuration file of our virtual host

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/your_config.conf
```

and add in the following directive

```
<Directory /var/www/your_root_directory>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

note: change your directory path

now our file should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/your_root_directory>

        . . .

    </Directory>
    ServerName midomain.com
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Now Restart the service of apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

create a .htacces file in your root directory of your web site

```
sudo nano /var/www/your_root_directory/.htaccess
```

and finally add into .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-json/wp/v2/posts$ ?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts [NC]
```

Comment: I wish you explained the "Why" of anything you instructed people to do here.

Answer (score 0):

This may help who face same problem after choosing pretty links in WP:

https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/497#issuecomment-420405995

I will put this answer here to stay even original is deleted.

> From: ecker00

While this is old, people still seems to find this thread when looking for issues with 404 on wp-json, judging by all the emojis on the previous post. Thought I would share my solution, as my Nginx config was:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
}
```

Removing =404 at the end solves it, but if you don't want wordpress to handle 404 pages it's better to add this in bellow:

```
location /wp-json/ { # Resolves WP Gutenberg 404 issue
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `index.php` after your root link:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/311792)