# Getting 404 when trying to access WP JSON API on localhost?

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I have seen a number of posts addressing this (such as [404 on http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts in wordpress using REST API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750315/404-on-http-localhost-wp-json-wp-v2-posts-in-wordpress-using-rest-api-v2)) but none of the suggestions have worked.  I've tried

- chmod'ing wp-content to 777
- changing the permalinks to something other than 'plain' (and also changing them to plain and then back again)

I'm trying to access the JSON API from a localhost installation but keep getting a 404 error. Perhaps it's my URL?

I'm trying to access

`http://localhost/wp/v2/posts`

and I get 404

Someone suggested

`/wp-json/wp/v2/`

but that didn't work either.

`http://localhost/wordpress` pulls up the WP page just fine.

I am running this under MAMP Apache on MacOS.  WP 5.1.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The trick (in my case) was to include `wordpress` in the route.  Thus

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

works just fine